# AngularJS ngIf object has attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
{
    selector: "departureDate",
    selectorName: "Departure Date",
    constraints: ["GreaterThan", "LessThan", "Equals", "NotEquals"],
    valueType: "Date"
}, {
    selector: "arrivalDay",
    selectorName: "Arrival day(of week)",
    constraints: ["In"],
    valueType: "ChoiceList",
    valueChoices: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
}
```

Now I want to do this in my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" *ngIf="prototype.valueChoices">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.valueChoice">
                <option *ngFor="#valueChoice of prototype.valueChoices" [value]="constraint">
                    {{ valueChoice }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Is it possible to check if the object contains an attribute like valueChoices than show the HTML like above. Or is this not the right way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could use `Elvis` operator

```
*ngIf="prototype?.valueChoices"
```

Where `?` will act like a ternary operator. Here `prototype?`'s `?` will ensure that next expression `.valueChoices` would get read until `prototype` has value. The advantage of using `Elvis` operator is you can `n` number of `?` to handle variable existence check like `a?.b?.?c.?d`